# Estructuras Dinámicas Java

Tags: java, lista, estructuras-de-datos

hoy en la escuela me han dejado un trabajo en java.

A lo que hice y entendí hice esto:
-Cree cuatro clases

Clase Elemento:

```
public class Elemento extends Producto {
    Elemento Siguiente;
    
    public Elemento(){
        Siguiente = null;
    }

    public Elemento(String id, String marca, double precio) {
        Siguiente = null;
        super.Id = id;
        super.Marca = marca;
        super.Precio = precio;
    }  
}
```

Clase Lista:

```
public class Lista{
 Elemento Inicio = null;
 Elemento Actual = null;
 Elemento temp = null;

 
 public void insertar(String id, String marca, double precio) {
 if(Inicio == null){
 Inicio = new Elemento(id, marca, precio);
 Actual = Inicio;
 }
 else {
 while(Actual.Siguiente != null) {
 Actual = Actual.Siguiente;
 }
 temp = new Elemento(id, marca, precio);
 Actual.Siguiente = temp;
 Actual = temp;
 }
 }

public String mostrar_datos(){
 //Variable para sacar los datos
 String Salida = "";
 //Contador
 int contar = 1;
 Actual = Inicio;
 while(Actual != null) {
 Salida = Salida + "Elemento: " + contar++;
 Salida = Salida + "\nID: " ;
 Salida = Salida + Actual.Id + "\n";
 Salida = Salida + "MARCA: ";
 Salida = Salida + Actual.Marca + "\n";
 Salida = Salida + "PRECIO: $";
 Salida = Salida + Actual.Precio + "\n";
 Salida = Salida + "----------------\n";
 //Avanzamos a Actual
 Actual = Actual.Siguiente;
 }
 Actual = Inicio;
 return Salida;
    }
}
```

Clase Producto:

```
public class Producto {
    String Id;
    String Marca;
    double Precio;
public Producto(){
    Id ="";
    Marca="";
    Precio = 0.0;
}
}
```

Y la ultima clase es el JFrame tal y como está en el ejemplo del enlace que dejé
el cual llamé "Menú"
El código que añadí a esta clase fue el siguiente:

```
public class Menu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Lista Tienda;
    public Menu() {
        initComponents();
        Tienda = new Lista();
    }
```

En el mismo Frame en el boton de "Agregar" pusé el código con el evento onClick:

```
  Tienda.insertar(txtId.getText(), txtMarca.getText(), Double.parseDouble(txtPrecio.getText()));
     txtId.setText("");
     txtMarca.setText("");
     txtPrecio.setText("");
```

Al momento de dar click en el boton de agregar, agrega el producto sin problemas, el problema es al seguir a la siguiente parte de trabajo el cual dice así:

"Si el usuario da un clic en el botón de inicio |<  mostrará en los objetos textField los datos del primer elemento y si la estructura esta vacía mostrara un mensaje de alerta avisando al usuario que la estructura está vacía.

Si el usuario da un clic en el botón de avanzar >  mostrará en los objetos textField los datos del siguiente elemento y si la estructura está vacía o está en el último elemento mostrara un mensaje de alerta avisando al usuario.

Tendrás que agregar los métodos correspondientes para extraer los datos en la clase Lista."

Estuve intentando meter este codigo en el boton:

```
 txtId.setText(Tienda.mostrar_datos());  *
```

*Dejando el método mostrar_datos(); de esta manera):

```
     public String mostrar_datos(){
 String Salida = "";
 Actual = Inicio;
 while(Actual != null) {
 Salida = Salida + Actual.Id + "\n";
 Actual = Actual.Siguiente;
 }
 Actual = Inicio;
 return Salida;
 }
```

Pensando en crear 3 metodos para cada textfield "ID", "MARCA", "PRECIO".
Quizá me esté complicando mucho pero realmente llevo horas pensando y no sé como lo podría hacer, disculpen mi ignorancia soy nuevo en este mundo y no tengo idea como lograr hacer mi trabajo

Comment: Creo que en sí no dices exactamente cual es el error, problema o duda

Comment: Hice incapié en está parte de mi redacción:

el problema es al seguir a la siguiente parte de trabajo el cual dice así:

"Si el usuario da un clic en el botón de inicio |< mostrará en los objetos textField los datos del primer elemento y si la estructura esta vacía mostrara un mensaje de alerta avisando al usuario que la estructura está vacía.

Si el usuario da un clic en el botón de avanzar > mostrará en los objetos textField los datos del siguiente elemento y si la estructura está vacía o está en el último elemento mostrara un mensaje de alerta avisando al usuario.

Comment: Pero después pusiste una fracción de código con el cual lo intentaste, ahí que fue lo que ocurrió?

Comment: Ingreso un dato y al dar click en el botón me muestra el Id correctamente, paso a agregar un nuevo dato y al darle click nuevamente en el text field me sobrescribe el dato por ejemplo si agregue dos productos uno con el Id "1" y otro con el "5" al dar click en el boton me sale "15" en ves de "1" y posteriormente a otro click "5"

Comment: Es por que estás concatenando los Id Salida = Salida + Actual.Id + "\n"; en vez de eso intenta Salida = Actual.Id; si tu txt es un JTextField me parece innecesario el salto de linea "\n"

Comment: Lo intenté de la manera que me dijiste y funciona en cierto modo, pero si agrego tres productos al dar click en el boton ahora me muestra el Id del último producto que agregue, como lo podría poner para que me muestre en orden con cada click, del 1 al 3 sin saltarme los Id de los primeros 2 productos? Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: hace tu tarea solo

Comment: Shassain lo he intentado, creo que si estoy pidiendo ayuda es por qué en verdad ya no puedo, sólo me hace falta una pequeña cosa, lo demás lo he terminado por mis medios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que si observas el método recorres toda la lista y es por eso que siempre te regresa solo el último para eso intenta esto

```
public String mostrar_datos(){
  String salida = "";
  if(Actual == null) {
    salida = "Se ha llegado al límite de la lista"
  } else {
    salida = Actual.Id;
    Actual = Actual.Siguiente;
  }
  return salida;
}
```

Comment: Lo he puesto así y me sigue retornando el último elemento añadido y después de eso me manda el mensaje del limite de la lista, pero sigue sin mostrarme los datos anteriores al último :(

Comment: intenta en tu metodo de insertar al final iguala siempre Actual a Inicio

Comment: Sr1871 de verdad muchísimas gracias por todo tu tiempo me sirvió mucho tu ayuda, iguale el actual a inicio y ya compiló como lo esperaba ya con esta base puedo terminar todo lo que falta, muchas gracias amigo, te debo una muy grande!